# How can I assign array values into object keys for other object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

So I have an array of objects `[{}, {}, {}]`
and simple array `[true, false, true]`

Is there any way to make first array `[{value: true}, {value: false}, {value: true}]`?

I mapped over the object array

```
const a = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}] const b = [true, false, true]  const c = a.map((item) => {...item, value: })
```

I don't understand how to assign the value from the second array.

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Please show what you tried then and explain the problem. Then we can fix it for you. That's how this site works.

Comment: Ok, sorry for misunderstanding of site rules, so:

-- I mapped over the object array
```const a = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}]
const b = [true, false, true]

const c = a.map((item) => {...item, value: })```


I don't understand how to assign the value from the second array.

Comment: Thanks. I edited it into the question for you, but next time please remember there's no need to post the code into the comments :-)

Comment: Okay, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map each element of the array to the object:

```js
console.log([true, false, true].map(el => ({ value: el })));
```

or if you want to overwrite the elements in the first array

```js
const arr = [{}, {}, {}];
const arr2 = [true, false, true];
arr.forEach((el, idx) => el.value = arr2[idx]);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your array of objects is called `objects` and your simple array is called `array`, then you can execute:

```
objects.forEach((o, i) => o['value'] = array[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of accomplishing this is by using the `unshift()` method which will add the new elements to the beggining of the array.

```js
var arr1 = [true, false, true], arr2 = [{}, {}, {}];
for(el of arr1){ arr2.unshift({'value': el}) }
console.log(arr2);
```

If you want to loose the last three empty objects in the array, slice them like so: `arr2.slice(0,3)`